# Custom middleware that bypasses chain in Compojure

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring

I'm trying to write a custom middleware that checks if user is authenticated by checking existence of :user key in request.

```
(defn wrap-authenticated [handler]
  (fn [{user :user :as req}]
    (if (nil? user)
      (do 
        (println "unauthorized")
        {:status 401 :body "Unauthorized." :headers {:content-type "text/text"}})
      (handler req))))

(def app
  (wrap-authenticated (wrap-defaults app-routes (assoc site-defaults :security false))))
```

But when I try to return response hashmap with 401 status, I get the following exception:
**WARN:oejs.AbstractHttpConnection:/main
java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.Keyword cannot be cast to java.lang.String**

Perhaps I don't understand the logic that needed to be implemented inside Compojure middleware. 
How do I write my middleware that breaks the middleware chain and just returns custom response or redirects to handler?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe in your case the mistake is in the `:headers` map, since the keys are expected to be strings and you're using `:content-type`, which is a keyword. Try this instead:

```
{"Content-Type" "text/html"}
```

Comment: Can't believe I made such a dumb mistake :\ Thanks, it works now